# How can I get set input files path runtime?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, directory, runtime

I need to select the path directory of my "files.dat" at runtime.

My Visual Studio project create a .dll (that is a Nutech plugin) and in the code it is just implemented a load functions of this files. So I need that the user can choose the directory of files to load to the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function must receive a name of an input file as a parameter and do exactly one thing: load data from the file.  Everything else (like showing a dialog) is responsibility of the user code.

Comment: I just have the code for load a file, but I'am interested to only select the directory path... is there a functions that implement this task?

Comment: @Cavs85 do you mean function to show user a dialog to select a directory? If so it depends on the UI toolkit you are using. E.g. you can use the [SHBrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.